# Why when you call method of parent from a second inheritance is from first inheritance?

Tags: java

I am confused:

I run this example and the results is 2.

I can't find any explication:

- so we have an F object.  This is called `x.fun(x)` here and a copy of an F object is sent to fun method.
- here we have `fun(D d)` where we will have a copy of x but in a D object.
- d.method() is clearly calling for me D method which return 1;

However the result is 2...what i am wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class D {int method() {return 1;}}
class E extends D {
    int method() {
        return 2;
    }
}

class F extends E {
    int fun(D d){
        return d.method();
    }
}

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Test2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        F x = new F();
        System.out.println(x.fun(x));
    } 
}
```

Comment: A variable is the type of the reference, the object itself can be any subtype. When you call `Object hi = "Hello"; hi.toString();` you expect it to call the toString on String, not the one on Object.

Comment: "a copy of an F object is sent to fun method ... a copy of x but in a D object" - no, this isn't C++. There's no copy here. Were you expecting object slicing problems here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `d.method()` method call executes the method that fits the runtime type of `d`.
- In your case, the runtime type of `d` is `F` (since you create in your `main` an instance of `F` and pass it to the `fun()` method).
- `F` extends `E`, and `E` overrides `method()`. Therefore `d.method()` calls `E`'s implementation of `method()`, which returns 2.

Comment: Just to add more, check [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), section 8.4.8 (Overriding) that might give some more clarity.

Comment: @HarryJoy Did you intend to write "Overriding"? There's no Overloading in this question.